# How can I install the Mist wallet at d:?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

Windows is running on my ssd und i want not to install the mist wallet at my ssd but everytime i try to install the wallet it installs instant on c: .

Answer (score 3):

Currently it is not possible to set the chaindata folder in Mist. But there is a workaround.

Download Geth seperately as a archive [from here](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/), extract it on your hard drive and run it with the `--datadir "Your Folder"` flag. Now it will sync to the specified folder. Now when you start Mist, it will connect to the running Geth.

Please note that the chain downloading/processing is significantly faster on a SSD than on a HDD.